# See "layers" of my iOS application in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm developing an iOS application inside XCode 4.3.3 for iOS 5.1. Is there any way I can get the simulator or XCode to show me the layers of views in my application? I'm getting rather annoyed trying to figure out which layer is on top of the other as I'm using a predeveloped framework.

Comment: Is your question tagged ogre3d for any specific reason? (It's not mentioned in the question)

Comment: ogre3d is the framework that im using and one of the child views in my application.

Comment: But your question if not explicitly about a problem with ogre3d, right? It's about how to display the layer hierarchy in the iOS simulator?

Comment: thats right, so it can be done?

Comment: There is nothing built in. You could probably recursively set a border on all the layers and their sublayers and so on...

Comment: You can also simply set a background color to each layer recursively